# Node/NPM: Can one npm package expose more than one file?

Tags: node.js, npm, browserify

I have made a JS library for web development, it consists of several modules, which build up multiple distribution builds.  It's fine when it is distributed over cdn or for example using Bower.

But now I'm trying to publish it with NPM so that it can be consumed using Browserify.  My question is how can I expose more than one main file *statically* so that they can be consumable by Browserify.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you don't need to do anything.

```
require('my-library') // will require the `main` entry point
require('my-library/some-other-file') // will require a different file
```

Comment: it'll work with npm packages as long as the file is included. if not, then it's a bug.

Comment: can you give an example directory/file structure for the code you wrote? eg. is `my-library` a directory containing `some-other-file`?

Comment: @PedroCattori `my-library` is the library name and `some-other-file` is a directory inside the library.