# How do I package a node module with optional submodules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify

I'm writing a javascript library that contains a core module and several
optional submodules which extend the core module. My target is the browser
environment (using Browserify), where I expect a user of my module will only
want to use some of my optional submodules and not have to download the rest to
the client--much like custom builds work in `lodash`.

The way I imagine this working:

```
// Require the core library
var Tasks = require('mymodule');
// We need yaks
require('mymodule/yaks');
// We need razors
require('mymodule/razors');

var tasks = new Tasks();    // Core mymodule functionality
var yak = tasks.find_yak(); // Provided by mymodule/yaks
tasks.shave(yak);           // Provided by mymodule/razors
```

Now, imagine that the `mymodule/*` namespace has tens of these submodules. The
user of the `mymodule` library only needs to incur the bandwidth cost of the
submodules that she uses, but there's no need for an offline build process like
`lodash` uses: a tool like Browserify solves the dependency graph for us and
only includes the required code.

Is it possible to package something this way using Node/npm? Am I delusional?

**Update:** An answer [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930967/node-npm-can-one-npm-package-expose-more-than-one-file?rq=1) seems to suggest that this is possible, but I can't figure out from the npm documentation how to actually structure the files and `package.json`.

Say that I have these files:

```
./lib/mymodule.js
./lib/yaks.js
./lib/razors.js
./lib/sharks.js
./lib/jets.js
```

In my `package.json`, I'll have:

```
  "main": "./lib/mymodule.js"
```

But how will node know about the other files under `./lib/`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's simpler than it seems -- when you require a package by it's name, it gets the "main" file. So `require('mymodule')` returns `"./lib/mymodule.js"` (per your package.json "main" prop). To require optional submodules directly, simply require them via their file path.

So to get the yaks submodule: `require('mymodule/lib/yaks')`. If you wanted to do `require('mymodule/yaks')` you would need to either change your file structure to match that (move yaks.js to the root folder) or do something tricky where there's a yaks.js at the root and it just does something like: `module.exports = require('./lib/yaks');`.

Good luck with this yak lib. Sounds hairy :)

Comment: It's a shame everything has to live in the root folder, but it will have to do. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidEyk agreed, I too wish there was a way to specify export-able submodules in the package.json instead of just letting anyway require anything in your module.