# How to require a file other than the npm main file in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

package.json:

```
...
"name": "mypackage",
"main": "src/index.js"
...
```

Directory structure:

```
|- src/
|--- index.js
|--- other.js
```

I can require `src/index.js` with `require('mypackage');`, but how can I require `src/other.js`?

If the answer is `require('mypackage/src/other');`, is there a way to make it so I can require it with `require('mypackage/other');` (i.e. teaching node what the source file directory is of your module?

Comment: I'd personally like to know the answer to this question. Thanks for the question Adding to favourites

Comment: Unfortunately I think the answer to your second question is no. I found myself wanting the same thing this week and looking into it, but I didn't find a way. If I'm wrong I'll be interested in the answer too. As far as I know, the closest you could come to that would be to make a `src/package.json` and `npm link` from `src/` when developing, and use its contents when publishing or do whatever you need with them when building the package.

Comment: if you want to use full path you should pay attention to your current directory from where you make require. For example if you make require from other folder in mypackage you need to write something like this: require('../src/other')

Comment: You could copy the files into the root folder as part of your publishing script.

Comment: Most projects with similar use-case simply place all their "public" modules directly into the package root folder, using sub-directories only for internal stuff.

Answer (score 15):

AFAIK You'll have to explicitly expose it in the root:

Directory structure:

```
|- src/
|--- index.js
|--- other.js
|- other.js
```

Then in `/other.js`

```
module.exports = require('src/other.js');
```

Now you can do `require('mypackage/other')`

Comment: @Shilpa it would work - this is answering the poster's more specific question of "teaching node what the source file directory is of your module"

Comment: oh I see. Thanks for clarifying !

Answer (score 6):

I'm currently looking into the exact same thing.

`Package.json` has a property called 'files':

http://blog.kewah.com/2014/npm-as-a-front-end-package-manager/

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

> The "files" field is an array of files to include in your project. If you name a folder in the array, then it will also include the files inside that folder.

But I have yet to find how to do a import/require of such a file.
I don't really see another point in listing these files other then to be able to `import/require` them?

---

I was able to import a file from a package if it was listed in this files array.

```
{
    "name": "local-ui-utilities",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "LOCAL UI Utilities",
    "main": "index.jsx",
    "author": "Norbert de Langen",
    "license": "none",
    "dependencies": {
    },
    "files": [
       "/colors/sets/variables.css"
    ]
}
```

I'm able to import the css file from the package using postcss-import:

```
@import "local-ui-utilities/colors/sets/a.css";
```

This probably isn't your use-case, but postcss-import just uses npm under the hood. So This should work for your use-case as well, I would think.

This question and accepted answer seem related:
[Node/NPM: Can one npm package expose more than one file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930967/node-npm-can-one-npm-package-expose-more-than-one-file)

Comment: "I was able to import a file from a package if it was listed in this files array." Thanks for the information but you didn't mention the syntax you used to import it!

Comment: when I do it no JS file is publish in the NPM anymore :(

Comment: if suits you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46115274/expose-two-or-more-node-js-babel-classes-in-a-npm-scoped-package

Comment: This is a misleading answer. The `files` array is effectively a whitelist of what npm should bundle up when publishing, so this "works" because you're telling npm to include that file in your bundle, but at the cost of *only* that file being included.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to explicitly expose the file in the root folder, but many projects (including older versions of lodash) do this as part of a pre-publish step. In fact there's [a package](https://github.com/patrickhulce/generate-export-aliases) that does exactly what @Creynders suggests, adding `module.exports = require('./path/to/file')` files in your root folder. A while back I wrote up a [guide](https://blog.patrickhulce.com/2016/09/15/exposing-multiple-exports-in-a-single-npm-package/) on getting started, but the gist is pretty simple.

**Install**

`npm install --save-dev generate-export-aliases`

**Configure**

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "generate-export-aliases"
  },
  "config": {
    "exportAliases": {
      "other": "./src/other"
    }
  }
}
```

**Use**

`const other = require('my-package/other')`

*DISCLAIMER: I'm the author of the package*

Comment: A good practice is to make prepublish script = "git ceckout prepublish-expose && npm run expose"

Comment: "postpublish": "git add . && git stash && git stash drop && git ceckout master"

Comment: npm run expose can do lots of work, or just "generate-export-aliases"

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Don't use `prepublish` anymore. Instead, use `prepublishOnly`.

## My own approach to the solution:

As no one has an idea of how to perform the desired behaviour, we can't stand still, the best answer now is:

### Solution 1:

From Patrick solution, and his package `generate-export-aliases`: we can add some npm scripts to automate the whole publish process.
Either you write your code directly in commonjs inside `./src/` subdirectory or you used some new shining ES feature transpiled in `./dist`, you will have your module files to be exposed, so add npm scripts:

```json
"scripts": {
  "expose": "generate-export-aliases",
  "prepublishOnly": "npm run expose",
  "postpublish": "git reset --hard HEAD"
}
```

*Or a more save scripts*

```json
"scripts": {
  "expose": "generate-export-aliases",
  "prepublishOnly": "git ceckout -b prepublish-expose && npm run expose",
  "postpublish": "git add . && git stash && git stash drop && git checkout master && git branch -d prepublish-expose"
}
```

### Solution 2: Without `generate-export-aliases`

You can use `gulp` task runner (transpile if needed and put the files directly in the root dir, no need to copy or move again).

Indeed, this is the exposing step, you can keep `prepublishOnly` and `postpublish` scripts unchanged and just change the `expose` script. Save time and build in the root dir directly.

Answer (score 0):

From node 12.7.0 there is the [exports][1] property of the package.json that can help you.

````
{
  "main": "./main.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": "./main.js",
    "./other": "./src/submodule.js"
  }
}```

If you have a lot of submodules and you want to export all files you can use a [subpath pattern][1]:

```//package.json
{
  "exports": {
    "./*": "./src/*.js"
  },
}```


  [1]: https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-patterns
````

Answer (score 0):

just import it as a simple file.

```js
const otherfile = require('./node_modules/other_package/other_file.js');
```