# Expose two (or more) Node.js Babel classes in a NPM scoped package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs

I have two Node.js Babel classes in a public scoped package and want to expose them both.

Classes in the public scoped NPM:

Index.js

```
export default class Index {
    constructor() {
        console.log("abc!");
    }
}
```

SecondClass.js

```
export default class SecondClass {
    constructor() {
        console.log("SecondClass! SecondClass!! SecondClass!!!");
    }
}
```

In the public scoped NPM I'm able to set only one main file:

```
"main": "./dist/index.js",
```

And in the usage project I'm trying to import them both but I'm failing badly!

```
import { Index, SecondClass } from '@my-scope/my-package';

new Index();
new SecondClass();
```

Dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1"
}
```

How can I do it? Can I do it somehow?

---

**UPDATE 1:** Even using the `files` in the package didn't work and make it worse, once I use it all `JS` files are gone when I install my scoped package in the usage project.

```
"files": [
    "./dist/index.js",
    "./dist/SecondClass.js"
],
```

---

**UPDATE 2:** I tried to use the `"files":[ ... ]` as mentioned before and once I was not able to find any workaround for this I posted an issue in the NPM Github: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18481

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many hours researching I was able to find a workaround using vanilla code but keeping the Babel usage.

For the main JS file in your scoped NPM package e.g. `index.js` you must export all classes like:

```
import SecondClass from './SecondClass';
import ThirdClass from './ThirdClass';

export {
    SecondClass,
    ThirdClass
};
```

And in your usage project you can import like:

```
import { SecondClass, ThirdClass } from '@my-scope/my-package';

new SecondClass();
new ThirdClass();
```

The package.json from your scoped NPM package only need to expose the `index.js` like `"main": "./dist/index.js"`.

Dependencies and versions:

- "babel-cli": "^6.26.0"
- "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1"
- $ npm -v: 3.10.10
- $ node -v: v6.11.3

Answer (score 0):

The common approach is to create a file named index.js such that it reexports the different modules in the folder:

```
/src
    /foo.js
    /bar.js
    /index.js

// index.js
export * from './foo';
export * from 'bar';
```

This will allow you to import directly from the folder instead of an specific file.

```
import {foo, bar} from './src';
```

Comment: I didn't get your approach, I'm using the packages so how would I use the `src` folder?!

Comment: It was just an example, the convention is to create an index.js file which exports the rest of your files.

Comment: did you try it? ive tried many approach based on your idea but none worked, do you have any working use case? thanks

Comment: You should look for an ES6 import/export tutorial, there is some background you need to know to understand how they work. You can also look for js libraries or projects on github, you will get the idea.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible, try this:

***Index.js***

```
import SecondClass from './SecondClass';

class Index {
    constructor() {
        console.log("abc!");
    }
}
export { Index, SecondClass };
```

***Usage***

```
import { Index, SecondClass } from '@my-scope/my-package';

new Index();
new SecondClass();
```

Comment: I very liked the idea but if I have multiple, more than two, is there any generic solution?

Comment: I don't know other solutions. But if we want to export many object, I think the good old one `module.export` will be sweeter but not recommended in your case.

Comment: Well, not sure why it cannot be compiled. May be in your can only export as `json` like your answer may work.

Comment: im giving a -1 because you have edited your question after my answer following my solution + your above comment doesn't make sense!

Comment: Np dude. Doesn't matter to me. I fixed my answer so that it won't cause problems for other people. Glad that you found the solution :)