# Allow export of Client, Server and Common modules independently in a single typescript npm package

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I have a project (lets call it FlatEarth) with client-only, server-only and common components. I would like to create a single npm package that allows importing from only the relevant portions.

For example, a client-side only project would be able to do the following:

`import { FeCommon, FeClient } from 'FlatEarth'.`

The issue that I am facing is that even though I am only importing the FeClient and FeCommon components, the FeServer components (request-promise) will cause errors in the build process (since they are not compatible with client solutions) since they are still being imported by FlatEarth's index.ts file.

The FlatEarth setup is essentially:

*index.ts*

```
import * as FeCommonStatic from './FeCommon';
import * as FeServerStatic from './FeServer';
import * as FeClientStatic from './FeClient';

export { FeCommonStatic as FeCommon };
export { FeServerStatic as FeServer };
export { FeClientStatic as FeClient };
```

*FeCommon.ts*

```
import * as stringStatic from './String';
import * as uriStatic from './Uri';

export { stringStatic as string };
export { uriStatic as uri };
```

*FeServer.ts*

```
import { ServerRequestHandler } from './Server/ServerRequestHandler'; // Depends on request-promise. 

export { ServerRequestHandler as RequestHandler }
```

*FeClient.ts*

```
import { ClientRequestHandler } from './Client/ClientRequestHandler'; // Depends on jquery

export { ClientRequestHandler as RequestHandler }
```

Comment: This is possible if you compile TS to ES6 and the consuming code uses tree-shaking bundler such as rollup.

Comment: Thanks @unional. I tried that (using Webpack) without success. I ended up just following solution (though it isn't exactly what I wanted) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930967/node-npm-can-one-npm-package-expose-more-than-one-file